# Shortcodes not working

Tags: permalinks, shortcode

I have `WordPress 3.2.1` and I have created a personal shortcode, everything works fine until I change the `Permalink Settings` from `Default` to `Custom Structure`.
The shortcodes stop to work permanently, instead I turn back to `Default` setting.

> Hello, I'm [birthday year="1975-03-25"] years old.

I've added `add_shortcode` function in my theme's `functions.php`.
If I add the new `shortcode` to the original WordPress theme `Twenty Eleven` in the `functions.php` file, it works fine!

my functions.php file:

```
function short_birthday ($date) {
    list($Y,$m,$d) = explode("-", $date['year']);
    return( date("md") < $m.$d ? date("Y")-$Y-1 : date("Y")-$Y );
}
add_shortcode('birthday', 'short_birthday');
```

this is the only thing I've added to `functions.php`.

How my theme can block the shortcodes? It's the only thing I've did.
Can I do something to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how your shortcode should be set up:

```
function short_birthday( $atts, $content = NULL ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'year' => 'default value'
    ), $atts ) );

    list( $Y, $m, $d ) = explode( "-", $year );
    $data = date( "md" ) < $m.$d ? date( "Y" )-$Y-1 : date( "Y" )-$Y;
    return $data;
}
add_shortcode( 'birthday', 'short_birthday' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the html view to paste the shortcode ? Sometimes html tags are copied when you copy the shortcode and makes it behave like this.

Comment: the only way to crunch the `shortcode` is to set in my page.php the function `echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="12" title="Contact form 1"]' );` it's the first time I get this kind of error

Comment: very strange indeed. I'm using it on more than 20 sites without an issue... I got the problem only once by copying the shortcode example on their website and it ended up like this:
<code>[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]</code>
and the <code> tag broke the shortcode rendering... That's all i can think off.

Comment: Could you try to disable every plugins and go back to default twentyteleven theme and see if it's fixed ?

Comment: Yes, If I simply use the default twentyteleven it works, but not in my theme

Comment: Then there must be something in your theme that disable the rendering of shortcodes. 
If you remove your custom shortcode, are other shortcode still working ?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that with a platform like WordPress it is very hard to pin point the problem as there can be hundreds of causes and with the ever growing template and plugins...anyways I had a case where it took me a long time to figure out so I want to share quickly here.

Check to see how your template files display the content of posts/pages. If the code used is simply the `the_content();`    then that is correct. In my case I had edited the template myself and this is something many plugins do for example to insert ads or etc.

I was getting the content using `get_the_content();` which does not apply the short codes, also check for any `apply_filters` that can disable short codes.